# How to read a csv file with 20mil records using node.js createReadStream without increasing "--max-old-space-size=4096"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, solr

I am trying to read a csv file that has about 20mil records in it using createReadStream, I am able to read the file when increasing the Node memory to 8gb but the process hangs/takes ages to complete when running with 4gb. Below is the piece of code i am working with.

```
const Info: any = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
try {
  if ('' !== pathDetail) {
    console.log(`File Read Stream started at ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`)
    fs.createReadStream(pathDetail)
      .pipe(parse({delimiter: '|', relax: true, relax_column_count: true}))
      .on('error', reject)
      .on('data', (csvrow) => {
        CsvData.push({
          x1: csvrow[0],
          x2: csvrow[1],
          x3: csvrow[2],
          x4: csvrow[3],
          x5: csvrow[4],
          x6: csvrow[5],
          x7: csvrow[6],
        });
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve(CsvData);
      });
    } else {
      console.warn(' file is missing');
      resolve([]);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error reading the csv', error);
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are trying to save this data in a variable. You will never have enough ram to do that. What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: Post it to solr. the file size is about 500mb

Comment: I would try to send data to solr in chunks

Comment: i am not sure if we can post this data to solr in chunks. The above code is just trying to read the csv and pushing to an array. looping through that array then using writeStream to post the file to solr.

Comment: Any reason for not using the integrated support in Solr for indexing CSV files directly? https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/indexing-with-update-handlers.html#csv-formatted-index-updates